# The name 'HtmlEncoder' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am teaching myself asp .net core. I am going through the [getting started guide](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/tutorials/first-mvc-app/adding-controller.html). In my HelloWorldController I have this method:

```
public string Welcome(string name, int numTimes = 1)
{
    return HtmlEncoder.Default.Encode($"Hello {name}, numTimes: {numTimes}");
}
```

But I am getting an error:

```
Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error    CS0103    The name 'HtmlEncoder' does not exist in the current context    TestApp..NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0    c:\Users\administrator\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\TestApp\src\TestApp\Controllers\HelloWorldController.cs    23    Active
```

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Add following line to your HelloWorldController:

```
using System.Text.Encodings.Web;
```

Or you can replace the line `return HtmlEncoder.Default.Encode($"Hello {name}, numTimes: {numTimes}");` with this line:

```
return System.Text.Encodings.Web.HtmlEncoder.Default.Encode($"Hello {name}, numTimes: {numTimes}");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the encoder package. Hover your cursor over the HtmlEncoder in return statement there it will show you the potential fixes saying find and install the latest version of this package online.

Hope this helps in fixing.